# Check system logs for "Service Battery" entry

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, logs

I would like to find evidence of when the "Service Battery" warning has been  activated. I knoow the console.app exists, but I'm not sure how to query it for what I am looking for.

Why I want to do this? I took my macbook pro for a screen repair at an Apple store. Upon return, I noticed this warning, which I did not see prior to the repair. I would like to know if this warning was first shown around the repair time.